# Wrong initial level loaded for packaged build

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, unreal-5

I am having an issue with Unreal Engine 5.2 initially loading "Temp/Untitled_0" as the level before loading the actual default level that I have set in project settings. I have the editor startup map, the game default map, and server default map set correctly to "MainMenu3D" but when I package my game for windows I have logging that shows that it starts with the Untitled_0 map and then deconstructs my UIManager class which had references that are lost from that point on. I also have the map added to the list of maps for packaging.

The UIManager is initialized in my GameInstance class (GameManagingInstance).

```
Warning: GameManagingInstance initialized
Warning: UIManager initialized with session parent menu: BP_SessionParent_C in object ID: 22451
Display: Audio Device (ID: 1) registered with world 'Untitled'.
Updating window title bar state: overlay mode, drag disabled, window buttons hidden, title bar hidden
Display: Game Engine Initialized.
Display: Starting Game.
Browse: /Game/Levels/MainMenu3D?Name=Player
LoadMap: /Game/Levels/MainMenu3D?Name=Player
BeginTearingDown for /Temp/Untitled_0
UWorld::CleanupWorld for Untitled, bSessionEnded=true, bCleanupResources=true
InvalidateAllWidgets triggered.  All widgets were invalidated
```

I also deleted the Binaries, DerivedDataCache, Intermediate, and Saved folders in the project, rebuilt, recooked, and repackaged multiple times with no change.

Comment: Looks like you have everything sorted out. I think loading Untitled_0 is just part of Unreal's life cycle. Other people seem to have it too (https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/assertion-failed-file-build-ue4-sync-engine-source-editor-unreleased-private-editorserver-cpp-line-1971-temp-untitled-0-untitled-still-around-while-trying-to-load-new-map-object-is-not-currently-rooted/453041).

Rather than that, look into why your UIManager is being destroyed.